# same song in B major and B minor

Tags: key-signatures

This song I'm learning to play-Flower Dance by DJ Okawari-is in B minor in one version and B major in another version. I don't know much at all about transposing and changing a song from a different key so I'm a bit confused. It doesn't sound that different to me, but how much of a difference in sound will this make? Sorry if this is confusing.

This is the sheet music I'm learning from ([from Musescore.com](https://musescore.com/mvmabaet/scores/5012125)):

[image]

But there are other versions at https://musescore.com/user/102470/scores/171373 and https://musescore.com/user/7745406/scores/4417756 that are in B Major.

Comment: Minor vs. major is no transposition task. Most likely, the song becomes a different one in the process.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, both of the versions you posted in the comments are in a major key; the first one is in B-flat major, the second one in B major. Hence, there is a one-semitone difference between the two. This doesn't make that much of a difference on how the song will "sound" nowadays, so choosing between them is basically a matter of how easy it is for you to read the score and play it on your instrument. (People tend to have a hard time when there are many accidentals in the key signature, so the B-flat major version is probably the safest option.)

**Edit.** Thanks for the comment @Dekkadeci, I had not read the scores carefully enough. Substitute every instance of B-flat major above with G minor and every instance of B major with G-sharp minor. The pertinence and meaning of my answer remain unchanged.

Comment: Based on the accidentals, the first example is actually in G minor and the second 2 examples are in G sharp minor.

Answer (score 1):

The G minor version has fewer mistakes than the other versions, which have been prepared by someone with little skill in music or in notation software:

[image]

It's hard to tell which version came first, but on a violin the G minor version will obviously sound richer and more resonant than the G#m version, the string-lengths being greater than if you play it a semitone higher.

Have you got an accompaniment for the G minor version? It is rather short of expression markings, isn't it? But what bowing there is is OK. Bar seven is wrongly notated: the tied A's should just be a regular quaver.

Comment: This does not directly address the OP's question. It would be better as a comment.

Comment: @Peter The question was "how much of a difference in sound will this make?" My answer was "the G minor version will sound richer than the G#m version: more resonant." I feel that directly addresses the OP's question. Please tell me why you say it doesn't. I also corrected him (and the earlier answer) in describing the piece as being in a major key. It is in a minor key. The only keys involved are therefore Gm and G#m. He said he was confused, so I tried to suggest he stick with the version above rather than the other versions he linked to which are hard to decypher. Did you look at them?

Comment: @Peter I'm hoping for a reply.

Comment: Your answer mostly involves criticizing the arranger of the music. The part about being more resonant is buried in the middle, and you offer no reason or explanation for it. You need to say why it's more resonant.

Comment: @Peter Where did I mentioned an arranger? I said "**prepared** by someone with little skill in music or in notation software." You didn't say if you'd looked at the other versions, so I've added a scan to my answer. Please look at it and tell me whether you disagree with my remarks about its preparation. The OP said, " I'm a bit confused" so I tried to steer him/her *away* from that confusing G#m version. Wouldn't *you* have done that? I've added a reason why it'd be more resonant. It seemed obvious: long strings resonate longer than short ones."Buried in the middle"?? Of seven lines?!!